# Best db field type to store and return total scores

Tags: mysql

I have a db table with the following structure

- id
- project
- category
- score

The 'score' cell can have the following values only:

- '' (blank)
- -1
- 0
- 1

What field type shall I use to store 'score' values in order for me to be able to get the total scores when I query based on project id? ENUM?

Comment: Have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6966

Answer (score 2):

why not use `TINYINT` (*you don't need any conversion*) for the numeric value.

```
Score
=======
0
1
2
3
```

*follow-up question, why do you need to have empty row or blank?*

Comment: Empty if the score does not apply to a particular project.

Comment: you can go for 0 if it does not apply to a particular object. :D

Comment: These are not my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use ENUM for the reasons of readability.
Later it could be hard to understand what exactly the number 3 or 0 means in your table, but with the proper name of the ENUM value you can easily identify it even after a year.

In additional. ENUM uses the same number of bytes (1) as tinyint in case when number of elements in ENUM is less than 255.